# Can't remove object from scene

Tags: three.js

I'm adding an object like this:

```
root = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(root);

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(300, 150, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x676767, wireframe: false, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
rect = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
rect.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
rect.name = "rect";
root.add(rect);
```

Then later I try to remove "rect" with this:

```
function removeEntity(object){
    root.remove(object.name);
}
```

no matter what I try I can't remove this object.
Any ideas?

Comment: `root.remove( object )` Not object.name. You can get object by name `.getObjectByName(name, recursive)` and then remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm ?

```
function removeEntity(name){
    root.remove(name);
}
```